# libcrypto.so.1.1 not found on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, apt

I don't have the library, libcrypto.so.1.1 on my Ubuntu machine. I checked on both, Ubuntu 14.04 and Ubuntu 16.04.

My openSSL version details are:

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

I tried running `apt-get update` and then `apt-get install --only-upgrade openssl` however it says that *openssl is already in the newest version*.

It seems that this library does not come by default with the OpenSSL package if installed through Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: An error running `docker-compose` led me here. If for you as well, upgrading using pip fixed it -- `sudo pip install --upgrade docker-compose`.

Comment: You could follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/44789238/3755161 to install the required libcrypto.so.1.1 library on your system.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [search results on packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libcrypto.so.1.1) - the `libcrypto.so.1.1` file is placed in `libssl1.1` package in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (and newer versions).

So you can not get it on 14.04 and/or 16.04 from APT.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no point in trying to copy it from ubuntu 18.04 either. Trying to run a program linked to it returns:

```
root@iperf:~# iperf3
iperf3: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1)
```

Comment: Yes, because libc is backward compatible, but not upward compatible.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error while running docker-compose. It turns out that if Dockerfile is in some hosted remote repo, doing `docker-compose up` shows the following error,

```bsh
unable to prepare context: unable to 'git clone' to temporary context directory: error fetching: /usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https: /tmp/_MEIBzMWvs/libcrypto.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_1' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh.so.4)
: exit status 128
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build : Build failed
```

Now, I needed to re-install docker-compose using pip by,

```bsh
pip3 install docker-compose --user
```

and when I reran docker-compose, it worked.